# In Python, For bar plot , How do I arrange X - axis values in ascending order?

Tags: python, matplotlib

New to Python. Below is the code I wrote to plot the Bar graph for the data I have

```py
K=df4.groupby('mnth_yr').sum()

K['sales'].plot(kind='bar', title='Monthly sales', ylabel='sales',xlabel='mnth_yr', figsize=(6, 5))
```

Output :

[image]

I need the X-axis starting from Jan'19. Please help

Comment: Sort the column 'mnth_yr' in the dataframe. You might have to convert the column to datetime and then sort it. Or convert it to 'yr_month' and then sort it.

Answer (score 0):

convert the `mnth_yr` column to datetime object - it is string type now and right now sorting is happening in alphabetical manner with 'A' being the first element.

matplotlib.pyplot bar function will automatically take care of sorting the x_label and plotting a bargraph

take this example -

```
>>> x_val = [10., 7.,  1.,  8.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  3.,  5.,  2.,  9.,  20.]
>>> y_val = [ 3, 10, 15, 37, 67, 380, 2758, 10369, 17824, 7661, 728, 46]

>>> for item in zip(x_val, y_val):
    print(item)

(10.0, 3)
(7.0, 10)
(1.0, 15)
(8.0, 37)
(0.0, 67)
(6.0, 380)
(0.0, 2758)
(3.0, 10369)
(5.0, 17824)
(2.0, 7661)
(9.0, 728)
(20.0, 46)
```

The data on x-axis is all jumbled up if you see.
Now if you run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(x_val, y_val)
```

[image]